# iOS sample "GLPaint" can't support orientations portrait, portrait upside-down

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I'd like to support orientations portrait and portrait upside-down on Sample code "GLPaint".
What's code this app support orientations portrait and portrait upside-down?

Sample code "GLPaint"
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GLPaint/Introduction/Intro.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007328

this sample use Object window not subclass `UIViewController`.
I tried this code, but didn't work.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
if ((interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) ||
(interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown))
return YES;
return NO;
}
```

i tried to modify the app to set up a view controller 2 patterns.

A:GLPaint add subclass View Controller.
B:New Project OpenGL ES Application add GLPaint.

Both were bad.
Currently, i don't know what wrong with the source code.

Answer (score 1):

Put PaintingView into built view controller, it works well on my side.
View Controller can control interface direction.